# QGIS List of two intersecting layers features inside Atlas

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, geometry, atlas, aggregate

Learning to use aggregates. Need to know how I can list several streets inside my atlas with the condition that layer 1 (not controlling layer, only visualised and used for statistical purposes) and layer 2 (not controlling layer, not visible in atlas) intersect. Layer 1 are points that mark problems, Layer 2 is street network. I want to list all streets with problems present.

This was my attmept:

```
 aggregate( 
 layer:='Layer 1 reference',
 aggregate:='concatenate',
 expression:="Any attribute",
 concatenator:=', ',
 filter:= 
 intersects(buffer($geometry,5), buffer(

 aggregate( 
 layer:='Layer 2 reference',
 aggregate:='collect',
 expression:="Any attribute",
 filter:= 
 intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))
 ),
 
 5)
 
 ))
```

I created a buffer around both geometries so that there is a chance for intersection of these two vector types. Making it larger does not help. The output remains empty. I dont know if I can use aggregate inside aggregate.

If it can be done, then how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The buffer in your 7th line can not work because it is not a geometry. The second aggregate collects an attribute, not a geometry.

Try something like this:

```
 aggregate( 
   layer:='Layer 2 reference',
   aggregate:='concatenate',
   expression:=to_string("Your Attribute"),
   concatenator:=', ',
   filter:=
    intersects(
      buffer($geometry,5),
        aggregate('Layer 1 reference','collect',$geometry)
    )
  )
```

Make sure the field to concatenate is a string (you can ensure it by using `to_string()`)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot seem to make it work. In "Your attribute" I have the street names attribute. The I fill in the references of the layers. No matter the buffer thickness, the result returns empty.

Comment: Are both layers in the same crs?

Comment: They were not, they are now and now it works. Awesome. Thank you kindly.